# \n to <br> and multiple \n to <p> question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

1. I use bbruby gem to replace text in bbcode with html.
2. It replaces `\r\n \n` with `<br>`, and mutiple `\r\n \n`s with `<p>`.

```
 # https://github.com/cpjolicoeur/bb-ruby/blob/master/lib/bb-ruby.rb

 def simple_format(text)
  start_tag = '<p>'
  text = text.to_s.dup
  text.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")                     # \r\n and \r => \n
  text.gsub!(/\n\n+/, "</p>\n\n#{start_tag}")   # 2+ newline  => paragraph
  text.gsub!(/([^\n]\n)(?=[^\n])/, '\1<br />')  # 1 newline   => br
  text.insert 0, start_tag
  text << "</p>"
end
```

It looks fine!

But when the text contains `<table>`, it becomes terrible! I want to avoid replacing `\n` when `\n` is in a table tag, and I try to replace `\n` in a table before bbruby replaces it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
text.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")
```

Should be

```
text.gsub!(/\r?\n/, "\n")
```

You could get into look-ahead and look-behind in your regex to see if you're within a table tag (depending on the version of ruby you're using, this may not be available to you). You may want to instead just start your method by splitting your string on table tags, giving you an odd number of strings. Run the regexs above only on even indexed strings. Then join the strings together with table tags. This would allow you to properly terminate and start paragraph tags and let you ignore the line breaks in the tables.

```
def simple_format( text )
  strings = text.split(/<\/?table>/)
  strings.each_with_index do |i, string|
    if i % 2 == 0 # even index == outside of table tags
      string.gsub!(/\r?\n/, "\n")    # \r\n and \r => \n
      # ...
      strings[i] = "<p>" + string + "</p>"
    else # odd index == inside of table tags
      strings[i] = "<table>" + string + "</table>"
    end
  end
  strings.join
end
```

That said, you may want to run away from regex entirely for this as the solution I described assumes that there are no table tags within table tags or unterminated table tags.

Comment: It sounds good, but still have two problem:
1.Text contents incomplete table tag will fail
2.It can't handle table tag that has attributes (like border, windth...)

Can you give me more tips, thx!!!

Comment: I'm not sure use of a regular expression is what you want here. You may want to look into using an xml parser to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

well, somewhat like this?

```
  def simple_format( text )
      return text if ( text =~ /(<table.*>)/ ) # return text unchanged

      start_tag = '<p>'
      text = text.to_s.dup 
      text.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")    # \r\n and \r => \n
      text.gsub!(/\n\n+/, "</p>\n\n#{start_tag}")  # 2+ newline  => paragraph 
      text.gsub!(/([^\n]\n)(?=[^\n])/, '\1<br />')  # 1 newline   => br 
      text.insert 0, start_tag  
      text << "</p>" 
  end
```

Comment: This solution looks like for the text which contain table tag, not handle \r\n in table tag.

Answer (score 0):

bbcode and HTML do not mix. In fact bbcode was designed especially to NOT allow html tags. Since this is the design of bbcode, I don't see ways to hack around it. If you wish to continue using bbcode, you should consider it's not going to work with HTML input.

As far as I know, bbcode does not have syntax for html tables. If you absolutely need tables, consider switching to a different parser, or allow a full HTML editor like tinymce.